# d3 Bar chart is not working

Tags: d3.js

I want to create an d3 bar chart. I got this below code from google. while running this code, page is being empty. In eclipse console also, no error/exception is being shown. In browser's console also no error is being shown.

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    var barData = [{
      'x': 1,
      'y': 5
    }, {
      'x': 20,
      'y': 20
    }, {
      'x': 40,
      'y': 10
    }, {
      'x': 60,
      'y': 40
    }];

    var vis = d3.select('#chart'),
      WIDTH = 1000,
      HEIGHT = 500,
      MARGINS = {
        top: 20,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 20,
        left: 50
      },
      xRange = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([MARGINS.left, WIDTH - MARGINS.right], 0.1).domain(barData.map(function (d) {
        return d.x;
      })),


      yRange = d3.scale.linear().range([HEIGHT - MARGINS.top, MARGINS.bottom]).domain([0,
        d3.max(barData, function (d) {
          return d.y;
        })
      ]),

      xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(xRange)
        .tickSize(5)
        .tickSubdivide(true),

      yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(yRange)
        .tickSize(5)
        .orient("left")
        .tickSubdivide(true);


    vis.append('svg:g')
      .attr('class', 'x axis')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + (HEIGHT - MARGINS.bottom) + ')')
      .call(xAxis);

    vis.append('svg:g')
      .attr('class', 'y axis')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (MARGINS.left) + ',0)')
      .call(yAxis);

    vis.selectAll('rect')
      .data(barData)
      .enter()
      .append('rect')
      .attr('x', function (d) {
        return xRange(d.x);
      })
      .attr('y', function (d) {
        return yRange(d.y);
      })
      .attr('width', xRange.rangeBand())
      .attr('height', function (d) {
        return ((HEIGHT - MARGINS.bottom) - yRange(d.y));
      })
      .attr('fill', 'grey');


  });

</script>

<div id="chart"/>
```

Please give me any suggestions to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't have an SVG object drawn so shapes were going all over the place:

http://jsfiddle.net/5hh3s1rj/

The main part I changed was this line. After that all the shapes were drawn within the 'canvas' correctly:

```
var vis = d3.select('#chart').append("svg")
```

Comment: Can i change(reduce) the scale numbers which is in yAxis? As of now it looks very congested.

Comment: I won't do the leg work for you ( ;) ) but have a look at this and see if you can work it out...

    http://pastebin.com/2BuGjvAA